# Only one item appearing on Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I need to make a list of products with their respective icons above but it only appears one item. There are 20 products total. How can I insert the other 19 items?

**Code:**

```
ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
prodview.LargeImageList = imageList;

                while (i < 20)
                {
                    var json = c.DownloadString(url + (i + 1).ToString());
                    var image = c.DownloadData(urlicon + (i + 1).ToString());

                    var dataDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json);

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();


                    foreach (var data in dataDict)
                    item.Text = data.name; 


                    imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
                    imageList.Images.Add(i.ToString(), new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(image)));

                    item.ImageIndex = i;
                    prodview.Items.Add(item);

                    i++;

                }
```

This version of the code already works. Answer below.

Comment: What's the platform? Xamarin? WPF? Something else?

Comment: I'm using windows forms

Comment: Ok - so you were asked to append your new version and not overwrite your original question as now everything reads like a mess.. and wont help anyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic has issues

> for i = 0 to 19 ..
>
> download data/string create new list item create new image list
>   foreach item in datadict set item.text
>
> add 1 image to imagelist
>
> for all items currently in image list (aka 1) add it to prodview
>   rpt.

so you only end up with 1 item, as you remade item list each time, and each variable each time.

you almost certainly want something like:

```
  ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
```

to be before the while loop.  The below doesnt need to be in a loop either - otherwise its repeating.

```
    prodview.LargeImageList = imageList;
    item.ImageIndex = i;
    prodview.Items.Add(item);
```

There maybe other issues - such as im not convinced about the images but.. start there

Adjusting my code some..

Your code probably should end up like

```
    ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
    prodview.LargeImageList = imageList;
    while(i <20)
    {
        var json = c.DownloadString(url + (i + 1).ToString());
        var image = c.DownloadData(urlicon + (i + 1).ToString());

        var dataDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json);

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();

// not sure what you were trying to do here as it would always end up with the last name..    
//        foreach (var data in dataDict)
//        item.Text = data.name; 
        item.Text = "item "+i; // giving it a name

        imageList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
        imageList.Images.Add(i.ToString(), new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(image)));

        item.ImageIndex = i;
        prodview.Items.Add(item);     

        i++;

    }
```

Comment: The result ends up being exactly the same. Only 1 item appears.

Comment: that doesnt make sense - because your while loop would have made 19 images in the list - assuming you moved the creation out.. otherwise you still have 1.

Comment: Your item text also may read the same because you fill it from a dictionary and just overwrite the same item.. but you should still end up with 19 things

Comment: If I move the prodview.Items.Add(item) line out of the 'for' cicle all the items appear but only the first one has an image. That same image it's supposed to be on the last item though.

Comment: Can you append your new version of code (and not overwrite what you originally posted) to your question as right now it sounds a mess.

Comment: That foreach part writes the name of the product in the item which previously was in the API.

Comment: Finally, your answer update with some little tweaks worked perfectly. Thank you very much.